# Why is react router throwing 'Cannot GET /example' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React, and I need to add some routes with React Routes.

I have installed `react-router` with `npm install react-router`.

This is the `main js` where I have to declare the routes

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactDOM, render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './Components/AppComponent';
import Example from './Components/ExampleComponent';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="example" component={Example}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```

Navigating to `/` works fine. But when I go to `/example` I'm getting:

> Cannot GET `/example`

error

What am I doing wrong?

This way I have the same issue:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/example" component={Example}/>
</Router>
```

Example Component

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Example</div>
    }
}

export default Example
```

This is the `Link`:

```
<Link to={'/example'}>aa</Link>
```

There are no errors in console.

After the change I'm getting this errors in console (Caused by the `Link`)

> index.js (line 27585) Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not
>   match any routes
>
> index.js (line 27585) Warning: [react-router] `Router` no longer
>   defaults the history prop to hash history. Please use the
>   `hashHistory` singleton instead. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#no-default-history

Comment: Fixed the update, `export default App` opposed to `export default AppController` and fixed the `<Link />` components.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example route is nested within your parent route so you should't need a `/` in `/example`.

Also you can try setting an `IndexRoute` with whatever your home component would be so that it has a reference.

Linking to the route would probably help so you can see what is coming up in the URL to make sure its what your looking for.

Your App component shouldnt really be rendering anything other than `{this.props.children}` because that is where all the components that the router is handling will be rendered, the router doesn't just render things from the main file it controls the routes and which components to mount in the App component(Usually called an AppController) so you need to build a Home component that will render at the `/` route and declare that using `IndexRoute` in your router then set Links between the components and if everything is done properly than you should be good to go.

Link:

```
<Link to="example">
  Click Me!
</Link>
```

Main:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactDOM, render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './Components/AppComponent';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Example from './Components/ExampleComponent';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router'


ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}>
            <Route path="example" component={Example}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```

AppController:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="routerView">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Example Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';


class Example extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              Example
              <Link to="/">Click Me!</Link>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Example
```

Home component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class Home extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               Home
               <Link to="/example">To Example!</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Try making a Link element to the `example` route and then clicking it, it might just be that its not using the proper type of history.

Comment: It seems to be different, now the url changes, but it loads the first Component and not the example

Comment: Can I see the URL please? Is it what was expected?

Comment: I'm at `localhost:3000` and after click the `Link` the url updates to `localhost:3000/example`. But the content still the same

Comment: Can you post your example component code and your app component code and if you're getting any errors in the console can you post those as well?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code of example, is very simple

Comment: Check update, I'm getting some errors with that code

Comment: This is giving me also this issue:
Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router`. Check the render method of `Header`.

Comment: Well it was just a stupid problem..

`import { Link } from 'react-router';` The Link must be between brackets :/ 
You help me a lot, Thank!!! Maybe update your answer with that, for some one else

Comment: It was all about the app.js file for me. Didn't know about this.props.children. TOTAL NOOB!

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same problem as the question.

After trying the above answer, I am still getting the same error, Interestingly, there is also syntax error in above answer where `<IndexRoute component={Home}>`
must be closed or self closed.

Two ways I could make my thing work:

**1)** Not a perfect way but other way of making it work is using `hashHistory`
Just `import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';` and modify Router as `<Router history={hashHistory}>`

Now URL, looks like http://localhost:5000/#/example?_k=a979lt

**2)**
You can use `useHistory` as well.

But this also adds # in the URL but it looks like
http://localhost:5000/#/example
Where query parameters aren't present in the link because we'll set them as false..

**3)** In my case, with `browserHistory`, if I use my Routes as localhost:5000/#/example
then it works fine and without hash it doesn't.

Check this link for more details for each of them.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md

**EDIT:**
Finally, I got my solution to make it work using browserHistory.
Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38585657/3241111

Answer (score 2):

as of react router v4, if you are using webpack with react you need to add `devServer` settings in your `webpack.config.js` file to prevent this issue. just make sure that your `devServer` config has `historyApiFallback` set to `true`, if it is not you will get Cannot get error in browser , i just put a simple `devServer` config from my webpack.config.js file that currently i'm working on , maybe helps someone....

```
module.exports = {

 ...

 devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }

 ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **exact** before the path of the App component

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="example" component={Example}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```