# React router not showing browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning from this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-media-library-with-react-redux-and-redux-saga-part-1) but I keep getting this error:

> 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

The file that has react-router is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you can refer to this link as it already has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063095/react-router-browserhistory-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Did you check github? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732

Comment: I think, you are using the latest version of React-router which doesn't contain the export browserHistory, rather than downgrading to a lower version, its better to change your code to work with the latest version Check these docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to get `browserHistory` from the [history](https://github.com/reacttraining/history) module now.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
```

Note that they changed the module API recently so if you are using the latest version the import slightly changed:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I wasted a couple of days to figure it out. This error happens simply because react-router v4 does not have the `browserHistory` (I don't know if that's a good thing or not though). I solved the issue by installing v3 like this:

```
npm install react-router@3 --save
```

Answer (score 4):

**You are using version 4 of react-router**.

Either downgrade the package or follow the instructions in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41701449/324497) to make it work with v4.

Answer (score 1):

> Simple Solution

**method 1:**

```
npm install --save history

use this now:

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
```

**method:2**

```
Use Version 3  

npm install react-router@3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import browserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
```

use

```
const routermiddleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory());
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory(), store);
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom version 6 `useHistory()` is replaced by `useNavigate()` ;

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home')
```

If react-router-dom version  less than 6

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
history.push('/home')
```