# Browser history issues in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run a project based on session timeout in reactjs.. But unfortunately an error occurs.. This is the error,
`'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.`

Comment: Are you looking for `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React router not showing browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063229/react-router-not-showing-browser-history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using React Router 4. It moves around some of those modules. You'll either need to migrate your code to use v4, or downgrade React Router in your `package.json`.

React router provides a migration guide here:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using react-router latest version. In new version history managed by internally. you can just use like and history is avaliable in your component props like `props.history`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { HashRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


let RootApp = () => {   
   return (
      <div>
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>                  
              <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={AdminRoute} /> 
              <Route path='/login' component={LoginComponet}></Route>
              <Route path='/**' component={LoginComponet}></Route>             
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
}
```